# What happens to eyelids when we feel sleepy?

Tags: eyes, endocrinology, sleep

Why is that whenever we feel sleepy, our eyelids start to feel heavier.

It is not like we can any time close our eyes and will immediately fall asleep. But, when we feel sleepy our eyelids automatically become heavy.

What causes heaviness of eyelids? Is it because of sleep hormone or something?